# PDF for ratio of Dirichlet

Tags: density-function, dirichlet-process

I have a random vector $\theta$, which was generated by:

`X1 ~` [Dirichlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution)($\alpha_1$)
`X2 ~` [Dirichlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution)($\alpha_2$)
$\theta$ = element wise `X1`/`X2`

What is the PDF for $\theta$?

---

Thanks at @Matthew. The author suggests approximating a Dirichlet with independent Betas. This approximation will lose the part I am most interested in. For example:

If $\alpha_1$ = $\alpha_2$ = [1, 1] then:
The pdf for $\theta$ = [20, -1] is > 0 and 
The pdf for $\theta$ = [20, 1] is = 0 it is unfeasible. It can't be generated through this process.

If I understood it correctly the paper would assign the same pdf value to both.

Comment: [This](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03610920008832632#.U7nyWnVdVNB) might be useful to you if you can access it.